How can I connect my websocket api correctly?
I have created a websocket API using this youtube tutorial https://youtu.be/qmi-FuEoK4c?si=VS5J-286ZC6C6Ith that uses python because that is the language I'm most comfortable with. On I keep getting this error message:
[ERROR] KeyError: 'connectionid'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 8, in lambda_handler
    connectionid = event['requestContext']['connectionid']

Here is the code I have on my connect lambda function:
import json
import boto3
import os

dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    connectionid = event['requestContext']['connectionid']

    dynamodb.put_item(
        TableName=os.environ['WEBSOCKET_TABLE'],
        Item={'connectionid': {'S': connectionid}}
    )

    return {}

How can I solve this?
I've read through multiple comments on changing the return to callback and that didn't work. I have checked the API execute settings on my sendmessage lambda and it's all correct.

Can you refer to the documentation where it says that the key 'connectionid' should exist in event['requestContext']?

Okay, it's from the office. So @mkrieger1 I'm confused by what you mean with "can you refer to the documentation where it says that the key 'connectionid' should exist...".  I tried to refer to that to figure out how to fix the code, but I'm not sure how to fix it. I am EXTREMELY new to websocket world and have only done coding at this depth recently. Sorry! I'm a newbie and confused!

Somehow you thought that writing event['requestContext']['connectionid'] would give you the result you want, and not, say, event['datastore']['itemName'] (I made this up). Why did you think that? Presumably you read it somewhere – where?

The documentation for the websocket integration shows connectionId, not connectionid.  If that's not the issue, you will need to produce more details on how you're calling this lambda handler.

@mkrieger1 I got the code from a file the person shared in their video with the python code for connect, disconnect, and send message. I've pasted the code next for reference. import json
import boto3
import os
dynamodb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
def lambda_handler(event, context):
connectionId = event['requestContext']['connectionId']
dynamodb.put_item(
    TableName=os.environ['WEBSOCKET_TABLE'],
    Item={'connectionId': {'S': connectionId}}
)

return {}


@AnonCoward Yes, it does. I mistyped it on the dynamodb table and labeled the table as "connectionid" instead of "connectionId", so I changed it in the code. My patience was nil yesterday when I finally figured that error out, so I could not figure out how to change the name of the table in dynamodb. I may have to just start over. sigh.
